# Where am I going wrong with my Dockerfile?

Tags: docker, path, dockerfile, executable

I've created a Dockerfile at the root of a directory that contains a web application. My Dockerfile reads as follows:

```
FROM openjdk:8u282-jre
MAINTAINER me <me@email.com>
COPY target/spring-petclinic-2.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar /
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["java -jar"]
```

I'm attempting to copy a jar file from my local machine using the path from the within the root of the project directory - copying this to the root of the container, expose port 8080, and use an entry point thinking that after building the image, the jar will be run as an executable using this entry point. I then built the image as follows:

```
docker build -t se441/spring-petclinic:standalone .
```

Giving the build the name se441/spring-petclinic:standalone, I then attempt to run the container:

```
docker run -i -t se441/spring-petclinic:standalone
```

And I am getting the following error:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:370: 
starting container process caused: exec: "java -jar": executable file not found in $PATH: 
unknown.
```

I edited the Dockerfile to have the entry point be a /bin/bash, did an 'ls' and the jar file is definitely there. While in the container, I can run the jar successfully. Any advice on why the jar file can't be found when building/running with the Dockerfile as I've listed above. would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Try replacing `ENTRYPOINT ["java -jar"]` with `ENTRYPOINT ["java -jar /spring-petclinic-2.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar"]`

Comment: Thanks. I tried this and got: docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:370: starting container process caused: exec: "java -jar /spring-petclinic-2.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar": stat java -jar /spring-petclinic-2.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar: no such file or directory: unknown.

Comment: If you use the *exec* form you need to split options, like `ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "your_jar_file"]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["java -jar"]
```

to:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar"]
```

The exec syntax (with the json array) does no do any command line parsing that you get with a shell, so it's looking for the literal binary `java -jar` rather than `java` and passing the `-jar` argument. You need to separate each parameter as another array entry, just as you'd separate them with spaces on the command line.

At that point, you'll find that `-jar` expects the name of the jar file. You can pass that as an argument when you run the container, e.g.:

```
docker run -i -t se441/spring-petclinic:standalone spring-petclinic-2.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Or specify that as well in the entrypoint:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "spring-petclinic-2.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar"]
```